# Personal log with mobile app

Tags: android, web-apps, note-taking

I’ve been using [Google Keep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Keep) as a kind of a personal online log and though it has some great features it doesn’t exactly fit my needs.

I’m looking for an application that has (at least) the following features:

1. Web app that can display the log entries in chronological order.
2. Support for tags and searches.
3. Android app that allows to add log entries with text / audio recording (preferably with speech recognition) / photos (video is a plus).
4. A simple UI.

Reminders and sharing options are a plus.

Comment: I'm not using any such app myself, but while waiting for answers you might wish to check my [list off note-taking apps with cloud support](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_notes#group_101) (they have reviews linked where available as well, and are ordered by rating – should make it easy to at least find some good candidates).

Answer (score 2):

## Evernote

### Availability

- Webapp ✓ → https://www.evernote.com
- Android app ✓ → [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evernote)

### Chronological order ✓

You can display by creation date or update date (I think the latter is the default). The webapp has some more options than the Android application.

[image: Sorting options]

#### Display as a timeline ✓

The notes (title, excerpts and pictures (pictures can be deactivated in settings)) are displayed in the selected order on the left. The selected note is displayed in full on the right side.

[image: Timeline view]

On an Android phone, the view switches between the timeline and the selected note. On a tablet, you can have both columns as on the webapp.

### Support for tags ✓

Two hierarchy levels: notebooks and tags. You may use one or the other, or both. Everything is up to you.

#### Notebooks

Notebooks are like files or folders: each note can belong to only one.

[image: Notebooks]

#### Tags

Tags are like color post-it: you can add as many as you want to a note.

[image: Tags]

### Search ✓

Both in webapp and Android app, though less performant with complex queries in the latter (the example I used in the webapp returned nothing in Android).

[image: Search in webapp]
[image: Search in Android]

### Multiple media for notes in Android app ✓

Required:

- Text ✓
- Audio: via attachment; speech recognition is not integrated but I guess you can combine with a dedicated app
- Photos/videos ✓

[image]

#### A simple UI

This will be left to the appreciation of each.

With great functionality comes more complicated interface.

What takes the most time getting used to (I'd say ten minutes at most) is the navigation, as you have much more sorting options than Google Keep where all notes are loose in the same place.

Comment: Does Evernote allow you to view your notes in chronological order (as a timeline)?

Comment: You van order by date created, date updated, subject, etc

Comment: @traveh I added some screenshots and answered one point at a time (yes, I'm unburying the dead, sorry; trying to keep things useful for the next askers).

Comment: Thanks. I tried Evernote a while ago. It's a good app but the recording+speech recognition in Keep is what I use 80% of the time. It's just so convenient to quickly record my thoughts and then I just look at the text. Usually the text is accurate or close enough to remind me my thoughts, and in the cases it's not, I listen to the recording. It might be a small feature, but I found it was too important and couldn't really give it up... :/